File names in RYL languages
ALL,
In LTR languages the file name is constructed as:
(volume:)/pathq/path2/.  /pathN/filename.ext
Now when I go RTL language/locale - is it done the same way? Or the volume/root and the filename are switched?
TIA!!!
P.S.: The reason for asking
If I have a database of DQLite on LTR system and move the file to the RTL system will I be able to parse the name with the same functions? I mean - does CRT knows where the end of the string is if I use ‘find_right_of()’?
